# Instruments freezes and restarts iPod touch 2G

Tags: xcode, instruments, ipod-touch

I can't get my application running with Instruments. I tried running it in Xcode with **Run › Start with Performance Tool**. Instruments starts, iPod touch 2G gets stuck and restarts every time. I'm on OS X 10.6.2, Xcode 3.2.2 and using iOS SDK 3.2.1.

Comment: Did you tried this with an SDK sample? This would help you to find out if the problem is with your environment or your settings.

Answer (score 0):

Running instruments adds a heavy load (both CPU and memory) to your device.  The iPod 2G just may not be able to handle your app under load like this with instruments.  Do you have a newer device that you can test your app with instruments to at least fix any leaks.  If your app runs fine on the iPod without instruments it'll probably be ok.